# Why functions.firestore get error despite functions.https doesn't?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I wnader why **await citiesRef.get();** in the **exports.createID** get error despite the same **await citiesRef.get();** in the **exports.newID** doesn't.

```
exports.newID = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
  let citiesRef = fireStore.collection('system').doc('uid_counter');
  let snapshot = await citiesRef.get();
  let counter = snapshot.get('counter');
  console.log('current counter = ', counter);
  res.status(200).send({ counter: counter});
  snapshot.ref.update({counter: coounter})
//  res.send('aho');
});

exports.createID = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  // ... Your code here
  const newValue = snap.data();
  let citiesRef = fireStore.collection('system').doc('uid_counter');
  let snapshot = await citiesRef.get();
  let counter = snapshot.get('counter');
  let id = hashids.encode(counter++)
  snap.ref.update({id: id})
  console.log(id)
  counter 
});
```

[image]

Any suggestions are welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `async` keyword:

```
exports.createID = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
```

> The await operator is used to wait for a Promise. It can only be used inside an async function.